# Building c program with gradle

Tags: c, gradle

I m new to building c/cpp plugin in gradle. This is project structure

```
.
|-- build.gradle
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- c
            `-- hello.c
```

Contents of hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Contents of build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'c'

executables {
    main {
    }
}
```

When i run : $ gradle mE , i get following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/sujith/Downloads/cpp-examples-master/gradle-c-plugin/03-executable/build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project '03-executable'.
> Could not find method executables() for arguments [build_aaxd7x5nukew1jgziyan9q177$_run_closure1@57552dfc] on root project '03-executable'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.297 secs
```

Sample project taken from https://github.com/ysoftdevs/cpp-examples

Gradle version :

```
$ gradle -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-02-16 05:09:33 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     586be72bf6e3df1ee7676d1f2a3afd9157341274

Groovy:       2.3.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_67 (Oracle Corporation 24.65-b04)
OS:           Linux 3.13.0-24-generic amd64
```

Am i missing anything?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The native build support changed significantly in Gradle 2.3. I'd take a look at the [Gradle User Guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

I am facing the same problem where using `executables { ... }` does not work and throws the same error as you have mentioned. Probably it was being used in an older version of gradle.

I referred gradle [docs](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html) for building native binaries.

I am used this code in `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'c'

model {
  components {
    main(NativeExecutableSpec) {}
  }
}
```

And your code should work fine with this.

After this you can execute `gradle tasks` to know what tasks can be executed.

You can run `gradle build` and run your executable as `build/binaries/mainExecutable/main`.

Sorry, that this answer is very specific to what you asked and I might not be able to help you generalize it as I am still learning how to adapt it to my `C` project.

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT**: You can also take a look at this amazing example provided [here](http://carlosvin.github.io/en/posts/gradle-cpp.html). Using this as a base you can enhance and improve your `build.gradle` file. But one small clincher here is that it uses `executables {...}`, `libraries {...}`, etc. which are probably deprecated, but it still a good read.